# RSA Digital Signature in PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, rsa, digital-signature

My requirement is to Digitally Sign a message/string, and once I have successfully accomplished that, I somehow need to attach it to the header of my web request, all this has to be done using PowerShell.

I think I figured out how to do it, but am still struggling on the actual implementation.

So far this is my PowerShell script:

```
  # loading the certificate I want to use
        $thumbprint = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        $cert = Get-Item Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My\$thumbprint -ErrorAction Stop


        #cast the privatKey object to a RSACryptoServiceProvider object
        RSACryptoServicePovider $privateKey
                            =  $cert.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider


        byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Hello World ... !");
        byte[] signature= $privateKey.SignData(***buffer, new SHA1Managed()***);
```

I am getting an error on the above line right where I put ***.

I am following the steps shown in this link for digital signature:
https://www.simple-tak.com/dotnet/.net-framework/beginning-with-digital-signatures-in-.net-framework/

And this one for loading the certificate:
http://powershell.orgwp/2014/02/01/revisited-powershell-and-encryption/comment-page-1/

Any help Would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why did you tag this ASP.NET?

Comment: What exact error / exception?